# Putting severals terms below each other

Tags: equations, syntax

i would like to put equations below each other and have equivalences next to it below each other as well.
Usually i use the command &= to put equations below each other, but when i use that it completely misunderstand the syntax.
Another problem is now that i have a line which is to long to fit in one row so i want to put the addition-symbol below each other and still want the equation below each. I tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P(X(t+h)=n)&=P(\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^n\{X(t)=k, X(t+h)=n\})\\
&=P(X(t)=n)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n)\\
&+P(X(t)=n-1)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n+1) \\
&=....
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But whenever i want to put another & somewhere to have the mentioned term below it, it completely destroys my whole syntax.

Second Problem:

```
\Leftrightarrow a&=b \\
\Leftrightarrow abcdefgh&=b \\
```

Here I have the equations below each other but i want the equivalences to be below each other as well at the left side or wherever i want to put them.

Comment: in which math environment you use your code snippet? is it `align`? in it your code snippet works fine ... welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Are you remembering to insert \\ to change line before use `&`?

Comment: Yes i am in the align environment. Yes i am putting \\ at the end of every line at the moment. So when i put & before \cdot for example it transfers everything behind that & like 5 cm to the right, but it doesnt matter where i put & its the same problem there.

Comment: In `align` if you use more than one `&`, it will try to insert another column of aligments on the right.  In your case, you don't want that. So, a single `&` on each line.

Comment: But then i have everything below each other, but i want the equations to be below each other and the additions to be below each other in one line.

Comment: we can only guess whats going wrong in your document if you not show it. please be so kind and expand your code snippet to complete small document, which will demonstrate your problem. without it we cant help you ...

Answer (score 2):

**edit:**
your question and additional request in comments are not clear ... now i added two more possibilities to arrange of your equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P(X(t+h)=n) & = P(\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^n\{X(t)=k, X(t+h)=n\})\\
            & \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\linewidth]
              = P(X(t)=n)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n)\\
                        +P(X(t)=n-1)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n+1)
                \end{multlined}     \\
            & = \dotsm
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
P(X(t+h)=n) & = P(\bigcup\limits_{k=0}^n\{X(t)=k, X(t+h)=n\})\\
            & = P(X(t)=n)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n)\\
            &\qquad +P(X(t)=n-1)\cdot P(X(t+h)=n | X(t)=n+1) \\
            & = \dotsm
\end{align*}
and
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\Leftrightarrow &\;& a        & = b \\
\Leftrightarrow &  & abcdefgh & = b 
\end{alignat*}
or 
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{array}{ccl}
\Leftrightarrow & a        & = b \\
\Leftrightarrow & abcdefgh & = b
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves one of my problems. Now in another case i want the equations to be perfectly below each other so i use &= and it works but to the very left i want to have equivalences below each other as well.

Comment: @chri11, sorry, i don't understand you. do you like that equations are left aligned and not at sign `=`?

Comment: I ad it to my first problem.

Comment: @chri11, one problem per question ... in the second case, if i understand you, just move ampersand. for example after arrows, or before arrows. or you like to have arrows aligned and equal sign? anyway, i suggest you to read some introduction text for writing equations in latex like https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics. it may help you to see all possibilities at writing equation systems.

Comment: Yes i want to have arrows aligned and equal signed aligned and thats not working with the & environment and i cant find it in the wikibooks either.

Comment: @chri11, but you have this solution in my answer (last example)!

Comment: If i use the alignat environment i have a lot of space between the equivalence and the first term :/

Comment: @chri11, last example use array environment, as i can see from my answer :-(